# Grails: 'integrity constraint violated' when child record was saved before the parent one

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Exception I get when saving child record before the parent one:

```
GrailsWrappedRuntimeException: ORA-02291:
integrity constraint (GRB.FKF8F6B734389E9766) violated -
parent key not found
```

The code:

```
class Child {
    Parent parent
    static constraints = {
        parent nullable: true
    }
}

class Parent {
    static hasMany = [ children: Child ]
}

def child = new Child()
child.save() // first save of Child

def parent = new Parent()
parent.save()

//session.flush() // the sudden flush

child.parent = parent
child.save()

// here is 'constraint violation' when transaction is committed
```

As it is said in the exception message, `Child` *has* parent key `Parent` set, but somehow the key is not seen as an existing row by Hibernate at that moment...

Above is a simplified reconstruction of events happening in my code. Please note these actions are performed in different places of code (designed to be separated from each other). Unfortunately such a minified code works well and does not reproduce the problem... Also I never met such problem before - I used to save child records before parent ones and vice versa without any problem.

I could fix the code in two ways:

- commenting "first save" of `Child` (ordering of saves is important?!)
- or uncommenting the session flush

Although I could fix it I really don't want depend on such things like order of save's or sudden flush'es... Any idea how to cure the problem still having reliable code?

Grails 2.2.0, Hibernate 3.6, Oracle XE

Comment: grails allows to save child objects in your parent using dynamic methods parent.addToChildren(child)... look here for more info.. [gorm-gotchas](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)

Comment: can you paste your exception log here ?

Comment: Probably your session gets flushed before the parent creation, without the real code it's difficult to say where's the error.

Comment: The exception isn't interesting at all: there is no any additional info (as it's usual for Oracle-side constraint violations). For example it raises when you do session.flush at the end of the sample code. The real code is private, but the sample represents essentials of it; and maybe I missed something... I'll try `addTo`, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is probably because you tested around without having the nullable `parent` constraint on your child table. Without having nullable there will be a 0 or something in your existing entries and new ones, becase DB is doing some magic. GORM will not remove existing FK and it will not add a nullable constraint to existing columns. Try to drop the constraints manually or drop the complete column. Double check for nullable constraint on your `parent_id` column.

Regarding your problem I would advance you to add the child on the parent, instead of saving the child to be a child:

```
parent.addToChildren(child)
```

This also implicitly saves the child, if it was not saved before.